# How to split DataFrame/Array given a set of masks and perform calculations for each split

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

You have 2 DataFrames/Arrays:

- `mat`: size (N,T), type bool or float, nullable
- `masks`: size (N,T), type bool, non-nullable

  - can be split to T masks, each of size N

The goal is to split `mat` to T slices by applying each mask, perform calculations and store a set of stats for each slice in a quick and efficient way.

Simplest implementation is via loop over each mask, however:

1. This scales linearly with T, which can make it slow for large T
2. Is it optimal to split and calculate in parallel, how would you do this?
3. Is it optimal to store the slices for each mask in a (N,T,T) tensor and calculate stats with matrix operations, how would you do this?
4. Would you implement with DataFrame or Array? given that we need to store results for multiple stats, DataFrame has some advantages.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

N = 1000
T = 100
t0 = datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
t_last = t0 + datetime.timedelta(days=T-1)

mat_np = np.random.choice(a=[False, True, np.nan], size=(N, T), p=[0.5, 0.4, 0.1])
mat_df = pd.DataFrame(mat_np, columns=pd.date_range(t0, t_last, freq='D'))

# This is just simple mask for example but in general it could be any bool array with the size (N,T)
masks_np = (mat_np == False)
masks_df = (mat_df == False)

results = {}

# Take first 5 masks only for example simplicity but in general need to apply for all masks
for date in masks_df.columns[:5]:

    mat_tmp = mat_df.loc[masks_df.loc[:,date]].loc[:,date:]

    # Example with 2 stats, could be more
    results[date] = pd.DataFrame({
        'stat_1': mat_tmp.notna().sum(),
        'stat_2': mat_tmp.cummax(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).sum(),
        # ... stat_X
    })

results_df = pd.concat(results.values(), keys=results.keys(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general numpy works faster:

```
results = np.zeros((mat_np.shape[1], mat_np.shape[1], 2))*np.nan
for i in range(mat_np.shape[1]):

    mask_tmp = masks_np[:,i]
    mat_tmp = mat_np[mask_tmp, i:]
    

    results[i:,i,0] = (~np.isnan(mat_tmp)).sum(axis=0)
    results[i:,i,1] = pd.DataFrame(mat_tmp).cummax(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).sum().values
```

On a generic CPU google-colab, this code required a `168 ms` wall time vs your pandas version that required `369 ms` wall time.

I was not able to "translate" your `mat_tmp.cummax(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).sum()` in numpy, so I chose to go through pandas with: `pd.DataFrame(mat_tmp).cummax(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).sum().values`. If you, only using numpy, find an efficient way to perform a cumulative max operation followed by an ffill, almost surely, the computation time will decrease further.

In order to parallel the loop you can define an helper function and delay it using `joblib` (`from joblib import Parallel, delayed`):

```
def helper_function(i):

    mask_tmp = masks_np[:,i]
    mat_tmp = mat_np[mask_tmp, i:]
    result_tmp = np.zeros((mat_np.shape[1], 1, 2))*np.nan
    result_tmp[i:,0,0] = (~np.isnan(mat_tmp)).sum(axis=0)
    result_tmp[i:,0,1] = pd.DataFrame(mat_tmp).cummax(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).sum().values
    return result_tmp

results = np.concatenate(
    Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(helper_function)(i) for i in range(mat_np.shape[1])),
    axis=1
)
```

Note that parallel loop becomes to be convenient only when `T>1000` (on my machine). You must test it on your environment and choose the appropriate solution also considering `N` and `T` values.

Comment: Thanks, this will reduce the time per loop iteration which is great, but what about getting rid of the loop? Is there a way to apply the masks simultaneously and store the matrix in a 3D tensor so that the stat operations can also be executed simultaneously?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't imagine how to avoid looping here, although I'm sure there is a way. Anyway you can further speed up the code by parallel loop. I'll edit my answer.